# Export followers from Instagram for another user?

Tags: api, export, instagram

How can I export the usernames of all the followers of a user (not mine) from Instagram?

is this possible with the API? or the unoffical API?

Answer (score 0):

The GET/users/user-id/followed-by endpoint will give you the followers of a user. This user will need to be authenticated and have granted you "relationship" as an additional scope parameter.